# pythonic way of comparing values looping over lists

Tags: python

From an API i got a "list of lists" containing different coordinates:

```
List = [[1.0, 2.5, 3.6], [2.02, 2.3, 3.1], [1.5, 6.5, 3.9]]
```

I have to find the minimum distance between two coordinates.
I did something like:

```
MinDist = 9999999999.
for Coord1 in List:
    for Coord2 in List:
        if Coord1 != Coord2:
            Dist = CalcDistance(Coord1,Coord2)
            if Dist < MinDist:
                MinDist=Dist
```

Is there a more "intelligent" (and faster) way to get this information?

Comment: No, there is not

Comment: What is `CalcDistance`?

Comment: is `CalcDistance (List[i]) ==  CalcDistance (List[j])` for any couple of `i`, `j` ?

Comment: This looks like a computation involving arrays consistent with `numpy` data types. So you can convert to `numpy` array and try optimizing with `numba` (JIT compiler). For loops, it's usually very effective.

Comment: CalcDistance is just the function calculating the distance between the two coordinates

Comment: This is not more or less Pythonic, but there is a faster algorithm for this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem (faster for large n, at n=3 it's likely slower)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a built in algorithm:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

List = [[1.0, 2.5, 3.6], [2.02, 2.3, 3.1], [1.5, 6.5, 3.9]]

dist_mat = squareform(pdist(List, CalcDistance))
np.fill_diagonal(dist_mat,np.inf)
i,j = np.unravel_index(dist_mat.argmin(), dist_mat.shape)

print((List[i],List[j]))
```

The code above combines [Find the index of the min value in a pdist condensed distance matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984767/find-the-index-of-the-min-value-in-a-pdist-condensed-distance-matrix) and [Numpy minimum in (row, column) format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230067/numpy-minimum-in-row-column-format)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `CalcDistance` is something like the below, you could use [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) and a key function together with [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

```
from itertools import zip_longest, combinations

def CalcDistance(a, b):
    return (sum((x-y)**2 for x, y in zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=0)))**.5

List = [[1.0, 2.5, 3.6], [2.02, 2.3, 3.1], [1.5, 6.5, 3.9]]

print(min(combinations(List, 2), key=lambda x: CalcDistance(*x)))
# ([1.0, 2.5, 3.6], [2.02, 2.3, 3.1])
```